# What is the equivalent of CAST( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as float) in SQL Server for POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql

What is the equivalent of CAST( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as float) in SQL Server for POSTGRESQL?

> select  STR(CAST( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as float), 16,15 )
> --output:44371.8189188657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

The exact equivalent is

```sql
SELECT extract(epoch FROM now()) / (24 * 3600) - extract(epoch FROM '1900-01-01'::date) / (24 * 3600)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get output like sqlserver? (output: 44371.8189188657)

Comment: Yes - simply adjust the starting point (1970 vs 1900).